# Example of using StreamingOutput as Response entity in Jersey

Tags: jersey

Can someone post an example of how in Jersey to set `StreamingOutput` as an entity in a `Response` object?

I haven't been able to find an example of this.

Answer (score 130):

See if this helps:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response streamExample() {
  StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
    WebApplicationException {
      Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
      writer.write("test");
      writer.flush();  // <-- This is very important.  Do not forget.
    }
  };
  return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

Comment: AAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGH.  I just spent four hours trying to figure out why my jersey rest service wasn't streaming a file.  I didn't put a flush on my writer. Sooooooo annoying.  Thank you for rescuing me!

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the JAX-RS V 1.1 spec nor the Java EE 6 Javadocs specify if the given output stream should be closed or not. Considering the preceeding comment though, I suspect you should indeed call OutputStream.close() instead of OutputStream.flush(). This may free some internal resources which are associated with the output stream.

Comment: Can `MessageBodyWriter` be an alternative?

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu You can also use a `MessageBodyWriter` but this question was about streaming with a `Response` object. With `MessageBodyWriter` you're obligated to write to an `OutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but how the heck do I get this StreamingOutput object out of the Response on the client side??

Comment: What is the advantage of this? Even when the client is not reading this writes the output which onto the connection. Can this write be called based upon the read from the client.

Comment: How do you read the output on client side? Everywhere I see examples of server side!!! :(

Comment: @koem If you use a proxy client with Jersey or CXF then Jersey and CXF procudes a StreamingOutput proxy object for you. So simply call the write method on the returned StreamingOutput object and provide an OutputStream it can write the bytes on.

Comment: @prongs + Nagyl: Yeah, I figured it out: InputStream is = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build().target(BASE_URI).path("/yourservice").request().get().readEntity(InputStream.class);
(all in one "sentence", it might be good to split this up into Client, Target and Response object)

Comment: @ChristianSchlichtherle: JAX-RS would be responsible for actually closing the output stream I would think.

Comment: @ChristianSchlichtherle: Looking at Glassfish 2.25.1 source (`WriterInterceptorExecutor.TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo()`), I see this code: `entityStream = new UnCloseableOutputStream(context.getOutputStream(), writer);`.  So I guess the answer no -- do not close.

Comment: put that flush in a finally.