# JAX-RS Jersey StreamingOutput vs Response getOutputStream

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I had look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012724/jersey-example-of-using-streamingoutput-as-response-entity)
which has nice answer on how to use JAX-RS StreamingOutput, but I think this StreamingOutput has the draw back it can stream the data only when we execute following code

```
StreamingOutput output; // do processing StreamingOutput                                          streamOut = null;
    if (outStream != null) {
        final String strStream = outStream.toString();

        streamOut = new StreamingOutput() {

            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                writer.write(strStream);
                writer.flush();
            }
        };
    }      if (output != null)
return Response.ok(new MultiPart(MULTIPART_MIXED_TYPE).bodyPart(jobInstance, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .bodyPart(output, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)).build();
```

I am thinking of useing Response getOutputStream instead of StreamingOutput in  JAX-RS class.
can any body please explain on this ?

Comment: What is `return if (output != null)` supposed to mean?

Comment: output is of type StreamingOutput