# Uploading a file via Jaxax REST Client interface, with third party server

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I need to invoke a remote REST interface handler and submit it a file in request body. Please note that **I don't control the server**. I cannot change the request to be multipart, the client has to work in accordance to external specification.

So far I managed to make it work like this (omitting headers etc. for brevity):

```
byte[]  data = readFileCompletely ();
client.target (url).request ().post (Entity.entity (data, "file/mimetype"));
```

This works, but will fail with huge files that don't fit into memory. And since I have no restriction on filesize, this is a concern.

**Question:** is it somehow possible to use streams or something similar to avoid reading the whole file into memory?

If possible, I'd prefer to avoid implementation-specific extensions. If not, a solution that works with RESTEasy (on Wildfly) is also acceptable.

Comment: What's the actual media type? `application/octet-stream` has a writer that can handle `InputStream`. Or I think [`StreamingOutput`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012867/2587435) even works on the client side for all media types, though I haven't tried it, but I imagine it _should_ work

Comment: It fully depends on file contents, but usually will be "application/pdf".

Comment: I'd try the `StreamingOutput`. I think I've used it before on the client side. I can't remember.

Comment: Have you tried simply putting the `InputStream` into the entity `Entity.entity(inputStream, "application/octetstream")`; AFAIK Jersey can handle it so I guess RestEasy should too.

Comment: I kinda have a feeling that `InputStream` would actually work for _any_ media type also. Have you tried `InputStream`?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings: Yes, you are right, it just works! Can you post this as an answer for the next person who searches for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReastEasy as well as Jersey support InputStream out of the box so simply use `Entity.entity(inputStream, "application/octet-stream");` or whatever Content-Type header you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

You can go low-level and construct the HTTP request using a library such as the plain java.net.URLConnection.

I have not tried it myself but there is example code which reads a local file and writes it to the request stream without loading it into a byte array.

[Upload files from Java client to a HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-from-java-client-to-a-http-server)

Of course this solution requires more manual coding but it should work (unless java.net.URLConnection loads the whole file into memory)

Comment: Yeah, might be that I have to use sth. like this in the end.

Comment: Interesting, I now made more tests. While passing `FileInputStream` (or even just `File` itself) to `Entity.entity()` works, what really transmitted over HTTP is a string "data:application/octet-stream;base64,...". I.e. not raw file contents which I hoped for. Server I cooperate with seems to handle that just fine, but it looks strange to me. Why not just put file contents raw? Encoding it first blows up size by a third *and* requires some extra processing from the server. And I don't see *any* benefits.