# Streaming xlsx file from resources folder corrupts the file

Tags: java, spring-boot, xlsx

I have a small problem which I've been unable to solve for a few hours. I am basically trying to stream an excel file from the resources folder withing a jar. The file has around 9KB in my file manager, however, when I download it by visiting the REST endpoint I receive a 13/14KB file which can no longer be opened by excel. The metadata is set correctly, as is the filename. I suspect the streaming/copying process is somehow corrupting the file. Here you may see the code snippet:

```java
    public void getTemplateByDataType(HttpServletResponse response, DataType dataType) {

        String fileName = "excel_template.xlsx";
        String templateDirectory = "templates";

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        InputStream data = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templateDirectory + "/" + fileName); // loading file from resources folder
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(data, response.getOutputStream()); // copying to httpservletresponse output stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
           //...    
        }
    }
```

I've already tried reading from a simple text file in the same location in order to verify whether the `getResourceAsStream` call works and this is the case. So I am somehow breaking something with the IOUtils.copy I guess? Does anybody have any suggestions why this simple code snippet breaks my xlsx files?

Just to get the full picture, the controller is relatively simple:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/templates", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    public @ResponseBody
    void getFileTemplate(HttpServletResponse response,
            @ApiParam(value = "Type of data import", required = true) @RequestParam String dataType) {
        importService.getTemplateByDataType(response, DataType.fromValue(dataType));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Streaming Output. Maybe this would help you [Example of using StreamingOutput as Response entity in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012724/example-of-using-streamingoutput-as-response-entity-in-jersey)

If you want to download as an attachment, then return the Response like below:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                        String.format("attachment; filename=\"download.gz\""))
                .entity(streamingOutput)
                .build();
```

StreamingOutput streams the content of the file and at the client end, it will be downloaded as an attachment.

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately the same issue occurs. The file ends up being bigger than original and I can't open it.

Comment: No it works really good. I have done it with file content, compressing file content. Everything works fine. If I get time, I will try to draft some sample working code. I recommend you to try and share the issues you face.

Answer (score 0):

try  to copy this file directly to your output stream.

````
@GetMapping(value = "/templates", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    public @ResponseBody
    void getFileTemplate(HttpServletResponse response,
            @ApiParam(value = "Type of data import", required = true) @RequestParam String dataType) {
       
        String fileName = "excel_template.xlsx";
        String templateDirectory = "templates";
        Path templateFilePath = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(templateDirectory + "/" + fileName).toURI());

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        try {
               FileCopyUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(templateFilePath.toFile())), response.getOutputStream());
               response.getOutputStream().flush();
               response.getOutputStream().close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
           //...    
        }
    }
    ```
````